# bashでのテキスト処理で１列目が同じ行の２列目を1つの行にまとめたい

Tags: bash, shellscript

bashを使って、１列目が同じ行の２列目を1つの行にまとめたいときどうすればよいですか？
図で描くと

```
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 4
c 5
c 6
d 7
d 8
e 9
```

というテキストを

```
a 1 2 3
b 4
c 5 6
d 7 8
e 9
```

というふうに処理をしたいのです。お願いします。

追記
テキストはすでにソートされたものです。結果はソートされていても、されていなくてもどちらで構いません。
使っているbashのバージョンはversion 3.2.57です。

皆様の回答やコメントを受けて追記させていただきました。

Comment: 元のテキストは(たまたま？）ソートされた状態ですが、処理後のテキストも並び順は考慮する必要がありますか？重複した列がまとめられれば適当な並び順でも（ソートしてしまっても）構わないでしょうか。

Comment: 元のテキストはソートされた状態のものです。説明不足ですみません。

Comment: awk でも良いのであれば、`awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] " " $2}END{for(i in a) print i a[i]}' input.txt`

Comment: sed なら `sed '-e :a;${;:b;s/\([^ ]*\) \([^\n]*\)\n\1 /\1 \2 /g;tb;};N;ba'`

Answer (score 2):

質問通りbashで実装するのであれば対象のテキストが`a.txt`に格納されているとして

```
unset -v HASH
declare -A HASH
while read k v; do HASH[$k]="${HASH[$k]} $v"; done < a.txt
for k in ${!HASH[*]}; do echo $k ${HASH[$k]}; done
```

でしょうか。Perl等、他のツールを使うのであればまた違ってくるとは思いますが。

Comment: 環境によっては動かないみたいです。試しに手元の環境で実行したらdeclareの`-A`オプションが認識されませんでした。https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays を見る限りは`-A`があるので自分の環境のbashのバージョンでは動かないみたいです。動作するバージョンが明記されていればより良いかと。

Comment: 私も試してみましたがmaotさんと同じところでつまずいてしまいました。

Comment: @ken 条件があるようでしたら質問文に追記されると回答する方の助けになると思いますのでご検討ください。

Comment: 2009年リリースのbash version 4以降の機能を使いました。特別に古いバージョンを使用されているのであれば質問文に明記していただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

入力が Field1 でソートされているとして、POSIX 互換 sh でごりおしするとこんな感じです。

```
input() {
   cat <<EOF
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 4
c 5
c 6
d 7
d 8
e 9
EOF
}

efficient_sh() (
    prev=
    while read -r k v
    do
        if [ "$prev" = "" ]; then
            printf '%s %s' $k "$v"
            prev=$k
        elif [ "$prev" = $k ]; then
            printf ' %s' "$v"
        else
            printf '\n%s %s' $k "$v"
            prev=$k
        fi
    done
    echo
)

input | efficient_sh
# a 1 2 3
# b 4
# c 5 6
# d 7 8
# e 9
```

Answer (score 1):

外部コマンドを使う例です。Bashの拡張機能は使用していません。

#### awkの例

Awkは標準的なコマンドです。基本的にインストールは不要です。

```
#!/bin/sh
awk '
    BEGIN {
        ORS = ""
        pre = ""
    }
    {
        if ($1 != pre) {
            if (pre != "") {
                print "\n"
            }
            print $1 " " $2
            pre = $1
        } else {
            print " " $2
        }
    }
    END { print "\n" }
' in.txt
```

#### datamashの例

```
#!/bin/sh
datamash --field-separator=' ' --group=1 collapse 2 <in.txt \
    |tr , ' '
```

[GNU datamash](https://www.gnu.org/software/datamash/)は標準的なコマンドではありません。多くの場合、インストールが必要です。
上の例では、データがカンマ（`,`）を含まない事を前提としています。

Answer (score 0):

[Yuki Inoue](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue)さんの回答の亜種です。
ソート済みのデータが同ディレクトリにdata.txtとして保存されていることを前提としています。

```
#!/bin/sh
set -Cu
#set -vx

while read -r key val; do
    if test "${current:-}" != "$key"; then
        current="$key"
        printf "\n%s" "$key"
    fi
    printf " %s" "$val"
done <data.txt
echo

exit 0
```